# My SPARQL request seems off. Advice needed

Tags: sparql

As a follow-up to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422550/correct-way-to-group-several-queries-in-sparql), I'd like some advice.

The solution proposed back there requires a 1.1 endpoint, which isn't what I have at my disposal. Plus, apart from the values grouping, I'm not sure at all that my handling of the count aggregate is optimal.

The information I'd like to retrieve is, for each ID of a list:

- its synonyms through the altLabel predicate
- its children through the narrowerTransitive predicate, EXCEPT if the id has more than 40 children, in that case I don't consider it an informative concept and would like to return only the count

As shown below, my solution uses an union and a filter in each part of the union. To handle the children and the children count, I have two separate subrequest. All that seems very off to me and I'd like to know if it's really how to proceed.

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX umls: <http://linkedlifedata.com/resource/umls/id/>
SELECT ?id ?childrenCount ?synonym ?child
WHERE
{
  {
    ?id   skos:altLabel           ?synonym .
    FILTER ( langMatches( lang ( ?synonym ) , "EN" ) )
    FILTER ( ?id IN (
      umls:C0013227,
      umls:C0013227,
      ...
    ) )
  }
  UNION
  {
    SELECT ?id ( COUNT ( ?childID ) AS ?childrenCount )
    WHERE
    {
      ?id skos:narrowerTransitive ?childID .
      FILTER ( ?id IN (
        umls:C3244316,
        umls:C0344315,
        ...
      ) )
    }
    GROUP BY ?id
  }
  UNION
  {
    SELECT ?id ?child
    WHERE
    {
      ?id skos:narrowerTransitive ?childID .
      ?childID      skos:prefLabel          ?child   .
      FILTER ( langMatches ( lang ( ?child ) , "EN" ) )
      FILTER ( ?id IN (
        umls:C3244316,
        umls:C0344315,
        ...
      ) )
    }
    LIMIT 40
  }
}
ORDER BY DESC ( ?id ) DESC ( ?childrenCount ) DESC ( ?synonym )
```

BTW, I've repeated the FILTER three times because it seems to be optimized away in the subrequests but not at the global level.

Comment: `GROUP`, `COUNT` and `IN` are all SPARQL 1.1 features.

Comment: `VALUES` is not supported so I guess it's a 1.0 implementation that has some of the 1.1 features implemented.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about about the features that the endpoint supports, rather than a problem in the code.

Comment: It's not off-topic in the sense that I precise which features are available and then it's just a SQPARQL request question. Anyway, it will soon be a year since the question, it could be closed, its interest decreases over time.